# Html.Action from Javascript include js var as parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am having trouble on calling a methode. I can do it with below codes but how to put in js var with my call?

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("surfacepost", "surface", new { text = "ThisSchouldBeAJaVar" })',
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
```

In fact this mthode is getting a partial as I am going to display. So if there is a better way of dynamic load a partial using js, please also let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the '@Url.Action()' method is executed by .NET, before the page is send to the browser, it is not aware of any javascript on the page, and the execution of the method cannot be influenced by javascript that is run after the page has 'left the server'

What you could do is create a placeholder, and replace it in javascript:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("surfacepost", "surface", new { text = "placeholder" })'
url.replace('placeholder', ThisSchouldBeAJaVar);

$.ajax({   
url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

Or you could just type the url and append the var:

```
$.ajax({   
url: '/surface/surfacepost/?text=' + ThisSchouldBeAJaVar,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for anwser. Your anwser seems as logic. But my [placeholder ] is not being replaced. I am getting [placeholder] string in mthode... Any good idears?